# language file naming conventions

Tags: language, joomla-4, manifest

Under Joomla 4 the language files for the core extension are no longer prefixed with the language code, e.g. en-GB.com_banners, however when I look in the manifest folders the files are defined with a prefix.

**Directory entries**

```
/administrator/language/en-GB/plg_webservices_banners.ini
/administrator/language/en-GB/plg_webservices_banners.sys.ini
```

**Manifest entry**

```
<languages>
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_webservices_banners.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_webservices_banners.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

When I add my own extensions with the prefix specified in the filename and the manifest then the filename retains the prefix in the `/language` folder.

Is the convention with Joomla 4 not to have the prefix in the filename?

Is there something 'stripping' the prefix from filename that I need to use to get my extensions to look like the core filenames?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use non-prefixed filenames in J4 (3.10 also supports this). Nothing is stripping the prefix, some core manifest files just haven't been updated.

Comment: That is OK, but how can the debris be cleared up? Assuming an extension has previously been installed with prefix, after it has been updated, it will install non-prefixed language files. But the old prefixed files will still be there, and will never be updated. Are they liable to be loaded? Is there a straightforward way to get rid of them?

Comment: On J3 the non-prefixed files would be loaded. Old files can be removed on update using an install script. See this answer https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32084/12652.