# How to remove a file from a template using the installer?

Tags: development, extension-update, jinstaller

I am developing a template for a small group of sites. In the old J3 days, I had to make an override for some core templates to fix some minor things. With the update to J4 this was no longer necessary.

I created a new release for J4 only and dropped the overrides from that release. After updating the template, it did **not** work. Looking into the files showed that Joomla did update but refused to remove any preexisting files. So, the old overrides were still active. I deleted them manually in the files and it worked.

Now my question is: **How can I tell the Joomla extension installer to remove a certain file during update?**

I understand that it is not easy to understand for the installer which files are from the previous installed package and which ones are created by the user/admin in order to do whatever (think of a custom `user.css` file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create an installer script. The provided generic installer, `Joomla\CMS\Installer\InstallerScript`, has some functionality for removing files and folders so you could extend it.

Create a file with class `[your_template]InstallerScript` in it, e.g. `ProtostarInstallerScript`. Populate `deleteFiles` property with a list of files to be deleted. Then in `update()` or `postflight()` method call `removeFiles()` method:

```
defined('_JEXEC') || exit;

use Joomla\CMS\Installer\InstallerScript;

class ProtostarInstallerScript extends InstallerScript
{
    protected $extension = 'protostar';

    protected $deleteFiles = [
        '/templates/protostar/html/mod_foo/default.php',
    ];

    public function update($adapter): bool
    {
        $this->removeFiles();

        return true;
    }
}
```

When using postflight method you need to check that it's an update that's being performed:

```
public function postflight($type, $adapter): bool
{
    if ($type === 'update')
    {
        $this->removeFiles();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Finally, declare the script in your `templateDetails.xml` manifest:

```
<scriptfile>install.script.php</scriptfile>
```